Garbled text / graphics on 2nd (external) monitor after upgrade to 24.04 wayland
I just recently upgraded to 24.04.1 and have been having trouble with text / graphics on a 2nd (external) monitor. As you type the text is garbled on the screen. It's really hard to do anything on the external monitor.Garbled text in terminal It happens with most applications.
If I drag the window to my built-in display, everything displays correctly. The problem only occurs on the external display. Graphics are also affected. Here you can see that icons in Dolphin are incorrectly displayed. The help text that is displayed when hovering your mouse over icons is also affected.
garbled icons
If I switch back to X11, the problems go away. They only appear when using Wayland on the external monitor.
I've also tried doing a clean install, but got the same results. I didn't have any problems before I upgraded from 22.04.
If anyone has any ideas of how to get this working correctly, it would be appreciated.
Operating System: KDE neon 6.2
KDE Plasma Version: 6.2.2
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.7.0
Qt Version: 6.8.0
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-47-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 12 × Intel® Core™ i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
Memory: 23.2 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630
Manufacturer: HP
Product Name: HP ZBook 15 G6
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Neon
Description:    KDE neon 6.2
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble
